# Get all the keys of a multiimentional array that match a specific value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$transfers =
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [agency_to_id] => 8
                [agency_name] => 3.1 SUCURSAL BRASILIA
                [product_id] => 415
                [product_code] => 111021
                [product_name] => PAN FELIPE POR KILO
                [ptype_id] => 54
                [ptype_name] => 1.1.01.1 PANADERIA X KILO
                [catalog_id] => 1
                [subject_id] => 3
                [label_id] => 300000002
                [total_quantity] => 12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [agency_to_id] => 9
                [agency_name] => 4.1 SUCURSAL CENTRO
                [product_id] => 415
                [product_code] => 111021
                [product_name] => PAN FELIPE POR KILO
                [ptype_id] => 54
                [ptype_name] => 1.1.01.1 PANADERIA X KILO
                [catalog_id] => 1
                [subject_id] => 3
                [label_id] => 300000002
                [total_quantity] => 8
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [agency_to_id] => 8
                [agency_name] => 3.1 SUCURSAL BRASILIA
                [product_id] => 416
                [product_code] => 111024
                [product_name] => GALLETA POR KILO
                [ptype_id] => 54
                [ptype_name] => 1.1.01.1 PANADERIA X KILO
                [catalog_id] => 1
                [subject_id] => 3
                [label_id] => 300000002
                [total_quantity] => 1.6
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [agency_to_id] => 8
                [agency_name] => 3.1 SUCURSAL BRASILIA
                [product_id] => 418
                [product_code] => 111028
                [product_name] => PAN INTEGRAL POR KILO
                [ptype_id] => 54
                [ptype_name] => 1.1.01.1 PANADERIA X KILO
                [catalog_id] => 1
                [subject_id] => 3
                [label_id] => 300000002
                [total_quantity] => 200
            )
    )
```

And I want to get all the keys of this array that match a specific subarray value, for example I want to get the keys that match `[product_id] => 415` and I should get the the keys 0 and 1

I have tried with array_keys but it does not work.

EDIT:

```
foreach ($transfers $key => $transfer) {
                     $found_keys = array_keys($transfers, $transfer['product_id']);
                }
```

So, your answer, devolves an empty array

```
 foreach ($transfers $key => $transfer) {
                        $filteredKeys = array_keys(array_filter($transfers, 
                                        function($item) { 
                                           return $item['product_id'] === $transfer['product_id'];
                                         }));
                    }
```

Can you help me please. Thank you

Comment: array_keys doesn't search multi-dimensional arrays. you'll have to loop on the array and search each sub-array yourself.

Comment: I would have posted the `array_column()` method from @sergio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your edit:

```
$found_keys = array();
foreach ($transfers as $key => $transfer) {
  if ($transfer['product_id'] === 415) $found_keys[] = $key;
}
```

Below the solution for the originally stated problem:

Use `array_filter` like so:

```
$filtered = array_filter($transfers, 
                         function($item) { 
                            return $item['product_id'] === 415;
                         });
```

to get all matching elements, complete.

To only get the keys, pass the result to `array_keys`:

```
$filteredKeys = array_keys(array_filter($transfers, 
                                        function($item) { 
                                           return $item['product_id'] === 415;
                                         }));
```

This works, because `array_filter` preserves the keys of the source-array in the resulting array.

Comment: Very efficient, +1! And OP's still free to adapt the callback to elaborate more complex filters if needed.

Comment: i can't make it work. because i'm inside a for each loop for transfers array

Comment: Then please post your code and state your real problem -- solving the wrong one wastes both our time.

Comment: I'm traversing the array in a foreach loop and passing the $transfer['product_id'] to your function @TomRegner

Comment: See my updated answer -- note the 'as' in the `foreach` expression, in case you get syntax errors with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for `foreach`:

```
$found_keys = array();
foreach($transfers as $transfer){
    if($transfer['product_id'] == 415){
         array_push($found_keys, $transfer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_column` and `array_keys` with a search parameter. Here is the example of how it works:

```
$products = array(
    0 => array('product_id'=>3),
    1 => array('product_id'=>4),
    2=> array('product_id'=>3)
);              

$keys = array_keys(array_column($products, 'product_id'), 3);
// outputs the key of the element that has `product_id` = 3
var_dump($keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops, loops and loops. That's the key. (Get it? Key? I'm sorry)

Anyhow:

```
$array = array(
    'bla1' = array(
        'subbla1' => 'subval1',
        'subbla2' => 'subval2',
        'subbla3' => 'subval3',
        'subbla4' => 'subval4'
    ),
    'bla2' = array(
        'subbla1' => 'subval1',
        'subbla2' => 'subval2',
        'subbla3' => 'subval3',
        'subbla4' => 'subval4'
    ),
    'bla3' = array(
        'subbla1' => 'subval1',
        'subbla2' => 'subval2',
        'subbla3' => 'subval3',
        'subbla4' => 'subval4'
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        // here you have $key, $value, $subkey and $subvalue at your disposal.
    }
}
```